# Check label value

Tags: jquery

I've nested HTML label & input tags without `for=""` attribute for labels, so I can't check labels easily with just a selecor:

```
<ul id="categorychecklist" data-wp-lists="list:category" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">       
    <li id="category-6" class="popular-category"><label class="selectit"><input value="6" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-6"> Action</label></li>
    <li id="category-7" class="popular-category"><label class="selectit"><input value="7" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]" id="in-category-7"> Adventure</label></li>
</ul>
```

I want to check if Label is "**Action**" or "**Adventure**" then check its checkbox input.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $('li label').text(); should work

Comment: @Sergio: Yeah, throw a `$.trim` in there...

Comment: You haven't told us what triggers your code to check these elements. If the user clicking on a checkbox is what triggers the checks, then see my answer below for a possible solution (with jsFiddle example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.trim($("li label").text())` is what you are looking for. This will give the text alone in the `label`. To check the checkboxes which have **either** Action **or** Adventure in them, you'd have to run a loop on the labels/checkboxes. I chose to loop over the labels.

```
$("li label").each(function (i) {
    //check if text has Action or adventure
    //this is equivalent to if($.trim($(this).text() === "Action" || $.trim($(this).text() === "Adventure")
    var isTrue = ["Action", "Adventure"].indexOf($.trim($(this).text())) != -1
    //search for the checkbox and change its property
    $("[type=checkbox]", this).prop("checked", isTrue);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8w9SC/2/

Comment: Thanks and how then select related checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in different ways, not sure what you need.

If you click on the checkbox

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    var value = $(e.target).val();
    var name = $.trim($(e.target).parent().text());
});
```

or if you just run code looking for it

```
$('li label').each(function () {
    var name = $.trim($(this).text()); //name of the label
    var value = $(this).closest('li').val(); //value of the input of that label
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to check which checkbox the user just checked, this should work for you:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywykQ/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('[id^=in-category]').click(function() {
            var xx = $(this).parent().text();
            alert(xx);
            var yy = $(this).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
            alert(yy);
        });

    }); //END $(document).ready()
</script>
```